# Why Heroku + voila ipynb app fail to deploy with `failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Tags: heroku, jupyter-notebook, voila

I followed the different pages to deploy a voila ipynb app on heroku:
https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/deploy-jupyter-notebook-voila-heroku.html
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-jupyter-notebook-as-a-web-app-with-heroku-d157b68bcccc
https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-heroku

Unfoprtunately, it seems that there is a persisting bug this last month (saw here for instance https://forums.fast.ai/t/heroku-app-wont-deploy/92875/4)

You can find the github repo I am trying to deploy here:
https://github.com/vpicouet/fireball2-etc

The app is base on this Procfile
`web: voila --port=$PORT --no-browser --enable_nbextensions=True notebooks/ETC.ipynb`

Unfortunately I get this error

```
2022-03-27T15:17:49.880973+00:00 app[web.1]: [Voila] Using /tmp to store connection files
2022-03-27T15:17:49.881302+00:00 app[web.1]: [Voila] Storing connection files in /tmp/voila_yih2j7ic.
2022-03-27T15:17:49.881356+00:00 app[web.1]: [Voila] Serving static files from /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/voila/static.
2022-03-27T15:17:49.890735+00:00 app[web.1]: [Voila] Voilà is running at:
2022-03-27T15:17:49.890737+00:00 app[web.1]: http://localhost:7758/
2022-03-27T15:17:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-03-27T15:18:48.015586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-03-27T15:18:48.055996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-03-27T15:18:48.227953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-03-27T15:18:48.274554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-27T15:24:44.773897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fireball2-etc-2022.herokuapp.com request_id=0b0c1707-d6ae-449a-9059-f2d1d3f8c652 fwd="74.105.154.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-27T15:39:30.626492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fireball2-etc-2022.herokuapp.com request_id=af5c3e4a-019f-47c3-a047-e5115ebd5fc7 fwd="74.105.154.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Do you know fow to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

I already tried some ideas on the web:
change
`web: voila --port=$PORT --no-browser --enable_nbextensions=True notebooks/ETC.ipynb`
by
`worker: voila --port=$PORT --no-browser --enable_nbextensions=True notebooks/ETC.ipynb`

Comment: Cannot comment on your Heroku stuff, but voila opens when you try if via mybinder [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/vpicouet/fireball2-etc/main?urlpath=voila%2Frender%2Fnotebooks%2FETC.ipynb). The plot is blank, but I doubt that would cause what you are seeing. I do note you pin a lot of stuff and I was expecting it to maybe not work on MyBinder because of that. (Often pinning everything breaks because of a mismatch with things you cannot control or happened to miss.) So I'd try using an environment on heroku where you just use all current versions of dependencies and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The plot is blanck because I showed here a minimalist example to be sure there is no issue with the ipynb. The environement is pretty constrained so I don't think it is the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found here: [issue 1047](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/1047)

> From 0.3.0, Voila will not listen on all interfaces by default (#926) for security reasons. In the case of Heroku, you need to add --Voila.ip=0.0.0.0 to your command in the Procfile to make it work.

See also: https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-heroku